# Connection could not be established with host "ssl://null:465": stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: symfony, mailer, symfony-4.4, ionos

If I use **symfony/mailer** in symfony4.4 on the my **localhost** with mailtrap, it works. No error

But If I try on the server **https://my.ionos.fr**, it display error like this :

***Connection could not be established with host "ssl://null:465": stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known at /vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Smtp/Stream/SocketStream.php:138)"} []***

Can anyone please help me? I have tried in **.env** but no one is working.

#MAILER_DSN=smtp://xxx:xxx@smtp.ionos.fr:465?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login

#MAILER_DSN=sendgrid://KEY@default

Comment: Remove the `#` , that's a comment, so your configuration isn't being read. And both `auth_mode` and `encryption` were [removed in 4.4](https://github.com/symfony/mailer/blob/e129f1500ffa25ef8e2dfe039bb075dc02979840/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: I have tried this. MAILER_DSN=smtp://contact@xxx.com:xxxx@smtp.ionos.fr:456 It's not working also.

Comment: The [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/mailer.html#using-a-3rd-party-transport) states: "If your credentials contain special characters, you must URL-encode them". `@` is a special character.

Comment: I think the problem is not my config because when I comment out # MAILER_DSN =. I have the same error. maybe it's a problem with my myionos server.

Comment: I had this issue and it was caused by me not committing ./config/packages/mailer.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if you have any environment specific yaml configuration files, because they could not use ENV variables, but instead hardcoded ones.

For example you can have something like this in your `config/packages/dev/mailer.yaml`

```
framework:
    mailer:
        dsn: 'smtp://null'
```

Answer (score 3):

The origine of the problem is my config/mailer.yml
This file is missing in the server that way i have this error "ssl://null:465".